# Visual Studio Code Php Intelephense Laravel/composer no definition for Carbon

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I installed PHP Intelephense for VSCode and I got an error no definition found for Carbon. 
[image: That error is all the time I tried]

I hope You guys help me and sorry for me. I'm new here. :)

Comment: Can you post your composer.json file?

Comment: It works now I don't know why. I setup new laravel project and it works. Thanks for your time :)